# Safari extension - sharing session cookie with website

Tags: session, safari-extension

I have a safari extension that acts in favor of our website. It needs to share the session cookie with the website. The website sets session as,

> Set-Cookie: SESS=SESS_VALUE; expires=Sat, 09-Feb-2013 11:59:05 GMT;
>   path=/; domain=.MY_DOMAIN; HttpOnly

The extension makes requests using **Jquery**. The session is properly shared in all other major browsers including IE 7. But in safari, it maintains two sessions. My safari extension has the right domain MY_DOMAIN in its manifest file. I will be happy to hear your suggestions.

Comment: See this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272418/session-state-persistence-between-web-page-content-and-xmlhttprequest-for-mac-da. You might want to file a bug with Apple.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved?

Comment: As I can remember, I used workaround. Could not fix it at that time.

Comment: What was the workaround? Would be nice to share here.

Comment: It's 2016 and I have the same issue. I've debugged on my server and can confirm that the browser and the extension are sending different cookies for the same domain. Apple even rejected my extension because it doesn't always reflect when the user logs in or our of mu service...